# Finding Probability of identical and distinct objects

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

10 objects are to be distributed among 10 people randomly. What is the probability that at least one of them will get nothing?

Now, I had thought of two ways of doing it:

1. I assumed here objects to be identical.
   Hence total number of ways in which 10 objects would be distributed among 10 people is $\frac{19!}{9!10!}$.
   Further, the total number of ways equals every one gets something + at least one gets nothing.
   And, there is only one way in which every one gets something.
   Hence the number of ways in which at least one person gets nothing is $\frac{19!}{9!10!} - 1$.
   The required probability thus equals:
   $\frac{\frac{19!}{9!10!} - 1}{\frac{19!}{9!10!}}$.
2. I assumed all objects to be distinct.
   Hence number of total ways is $10^{10}$.
   Also, total ways = every one gets something + at least one gets nothing.
   Further, every one gets something in 10! Ways.
   Hence, number of ways in which at least one gets nothing = 10^10-10!.
   Hence the required probability is:
   $\frac{10^{10}-10!}{10^{10}}$.

The problem is that my answers are different for these two methods.

I strongly feel that the answer should be same irrespective of whether they are distinct or identical. How and where am I going wrong? Why is the probability of quantity dependent on the quality of the objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability of at least one of the people getting nothing, equals 1 minus the probability of all of them getting something. There are $10^{10}$ equally likely ways to distribute the objects, and only $10!$ valid ways in which this can be done. We indeed find:

$$1 - \frac{10!}{10^{10}}$$

The problem with your other approach, is that the probabilities of the ${19 \choose 9}$ possible combinations are not the same. For instance, the probability of all gifts being given to the first person equals $\frac{1}{10^{10}}$, while the probability of each person getting something equals $\frac{10!}{10^{10}}$.

To make this more tangible, try doing the same for two people and two objects. The probability of the first person getting both items equals $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}$, while the probability of both people getting one object equals $1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$. Indeed, the probabilities of the three possible combinations are not the same.